# How do I remove a model from a Backbone.Collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

I want to remove a model from a collection:

```
var item = new Backbone.Model({
    id: "01",
    someValue: "blabla",
    someOtherValue: "boa"
});

var list = new Backbone.Collection([item]);

list.get("01").destroy();
```

Result:

item is still in the backbone array ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also remove the model from the collection.

```
var model = list.get('01');
model.destroy();
list.remove(model);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have reservations about the accepted answer. When a model is destroyed, the "destroy" event bubbles through any collection the model is in. Thus, when you destroy a model you should not have to also remove the model from the list.

```
model.destroy();
```

Should be enough.

Looking at your code it looks correct: (If the intent is to destroy + remove, not just remove)

```
list.get('01').destroy();
```

Are you sure that your resource is getting properly destroyed? Have you tried placing a success and error callback in your destroy() call to ensure the destroy was executed? For example, if your model URL is incorrect and it can't access the resource, the destroy call would return an error and your collection will still have the model. This would exhibit the symptoms you outline in your question.

By placing the remove() after the destroy call, your collection will definitely remove the model. But that model will still be floating around (still persisted). This may be what you want, but since you're calling destroy() I'm assuming you want to obliterate it completely. If this is the case, while remove seems to work, what it's really doing is masking that your model has been destroyed when in fact it may not.

Thus, this is what I have a feeling is actually happening. Something is preventing the model from being destroyed. That's why when you call destroy(), then check your collection - the model is still there.

I could be wrong though. Could you check this and update your findings?